# WCF REST JSON argument polymorphism

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, polymorphism

I'm implementing `REST` service with `JSON` message format using `WCF`. I have a method that should take argument of different types (but derived form basic class). And I wonder if it is a good approach to use extended class with conversion operators in this case?

Example *(ommiting `DataContract`, `DataMember` etc.)*:

```
    class ClassOne
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class ClassTwo : ClassOne
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
    }

    class ClassThree : ClassOne
    {
        public int B { get; set; }
    }

    class ClassExtended
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int A { get; set; }

        public int B { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator ClassTwo(ClassExtended extended)
        {
            return new ClassTwo()
            {
                Name = extended.Name,
                A = extended.A
            };
        }

        public static implicit operator ClassThree(ClassExtended extended)
        {
            return new ClassThree()
            {
                Name = extended.Name,
                B = extended.B
            };
        }
    }

    void Test(ClassExtended extended)
    {
        // using as ClassThree here
    }
```

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used it with RESTful services in WCF, we use knowntypes all the time to handle  polymorphism on our DataContracts

Here's a link with more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

Comment: Can't get it working. There is an `InvalidCastException` when I try to cast argument to derived class. And if I mark base class `abstract` I get an error `Cannot create an abstract class`.